# Как правильно наследовать функцию Node.js

Tags: node.js

Пытаюсь передать в переменную request

```
function custFunc() {}
custFunc.prototype.one = function(options) {
    var this.requestCustom = request.defaults({
        timeout: options.timeout || defaultTimeout
    });
});
```

но при попытке вызвать функцию из другой выходит ошибка

```
custFunc.prototype.two = function(options) {
    this.requestCustom.get(/****/);
});
```

выдает: **TypeError: Cannot read property 'get' of undefined**

При этом вывов через request нормально работает, что я делаю не так?

Comment: Не понятно, откуда берётся `request`. И почему должно появиться свойство `requestWrapper`

Comment: лишний `var` перед инициализацией свойства `requestCustom`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

У вас лишний `var` перед инициализацией свойства `requestCustom`

```
function custFunc() {}
custFunc.prototype.one = function(options) {
    this.requestCustom = request.defaults({
        timeout: options.timeout || defaultTimeout
    });
});
custFunc.prototype.two = function(options) {
    this.requestCustom.get(/****/);
});
```

К тому же нужно понимать, что до использования метода `two` нужно непременно вызвать `one`;

```
   var f = new custFunc();
   f.one({});
   f.two({});
```

Теперь, если `request.defaults` возвращает объект с методом `get`, всё должно работать.

---

Возможно, можно воспользоваться паттерном `LazyLoad`:

```
custFunc.prototype.two = function(options) {
    if (!this.requestCustom) {
      this.one(options);
    }
    this.requestCustom.get(/****/);
});
```

---

*@PavelMayorov suggestion:*

```
function custFunc(options) {
  this.options = options;
}
custFunc.prototype.one = function() {
    this.requestCustom = request.defaults({
        timeout: this.options.timeout || defaultTimeout
    });
});
custFunc.prototype.two = function(options) {
    if (!this.requestCustom) {
      this.one();
    }
    this.requestCustom.get(/****/);
});
///

var f = new custFunc({timeout: 1e3});
f.two({id: 5});
```

Comment: Для ленивого выполнения параметр options надо передавать в конструктор, а не в каждый метод. Иначе будут побочные эффекты.

Comment: Добавил этот вариант, но подозреваю тут будут серьёзные расхождения с изначальной задачей автора(*которую мы, естественно, не видели*)